# Proof that interactive proof system is equivalent to generalized interactive proof system

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I did try to prove the interactive proof system and generalized interactive proof system are equivalent. According to both definitions are in the pictures. However, I still struggling to do it. Please help me solve this.

[image: Definition of Interactive Proof]
[image: Definition of Generalized Interactive proof]

Comment: So, in a generalized IP, the gap between soundness and correctness is now 1/p, for some polynomial p. How would you proceed to "boost" the gap of this protocol? What would be the procedure? Also, are you familiar with standard concentration inequalities?